# Show edges of a graph using Vis.js

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm trying to create a web API that receives a specific type of Excel, converts that information into a JSON and then shows it in table format and the form of a graph. My problem comes with the Graph. Currently, I'm using Vis.js and I have managed to create the variables of nodes and edges, both variables receive the values from the edges but for some reason, I cannot understand why the nodes are being shown while the edges aren't. I've been trying to look for a solution for this for a few days now and I decided to post this.

Does anyone know how can I solve this?

I've tried this:

```
function MakeAndShowGraph(data, container) {
    if (!data || !data.Grafo) {
        console.error('Graph data missing.');
        return;
    }

    // Crear un contenedor para Vis.js
    container.innerHTML = '';

    // Configuración del grafo Vis.js
    var nodes = new vis.DataSet(data.Graph.Nodes);
    var edges = new vis.DataSet(data.Graph.Edges);

    var visData = {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges
    };

    var StoredNodes= nodes.get();
    var StoredLinks= edges.get();
    console.log(visData.nodes);
    console.log(StoredNodes);
    console.log(visData.edges);
    console.log(StoredLinks);

    var visOptions = {
        nodes: {
            shape: 'ellipse', 
            color: {
                border: '#2B7CE9', 
                background: '#97C2FC' 
        },
        edges: {
            width: 20, 
            color: 'black', 
            smooth: {
                type: 'continuous'
            }
        },
        layout: {
            randomSeed: 42, 
        }
    };

    // Crear el grafo con Vis.js
    var network = new vis.Network(container, visData, visOptions);
    $(container).width($(container).width() * 3);
    $(container).height($(container).height() * 3);
    $('#changeview').on('click', function () {
        network.fit();
    });

    $('#DownloadImage').on('click', function () {
        var canvas = network.canvas.frame.canvas;
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        link.download = 'grafo_visjs.png';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    });
}
```